# How to give input value inside the selection option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here My problem is, When I select other option and I give some text values but it only print 'other' not my text value. How should I do this?

```
     <FormItem
        {...formItemLayout}
        label="Relation :"
     >
        {
          getFieldDecorator('Relation', {
                  rules: [
                    { required: true, message: 'Please provide relation!'},
                    { max: 200, message: 'Note should be within a 200 characters' }
                  ]
          })( 
            <Select
                 prefix={<Icon type="book" style={{ fontSize: 13 }} />}
                showSearch
                style={{ width: 150 }}
                placeholder="Select a Relation"
                optionFilterProp="children"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
            >
                <Option value="Father ">Father</Option>
                <Option value="Mother ">Mother</Option>
                <Option value="Husband ">Husband</Option>
                <Option value="Wife ">Wife</Option>
                <Option value="Brother">Brother</Option>
                <Option value="Sister">Sister</Option>
                <Option  value=" Other">
                    <Input placeholder="Other" style={{ marginLeft:-7,width: 140,height:32 }} type="text"/>
                </Option>
             </Select>
            )
          }
      </FormItem>
```

Comment: Are these custom elements? As you can't have a native `<input>` inside a native `<select>`

Comment: @patrickEvans sir yes .how do i do plz

Comment: that depends on how your components are made up, are you using `props.children` correctly?

Comment: You definitely don't mess with HTML. If you do, It will mess up with you in return. 
You should not use a textbox inside an Option tag. It is meant to hold only text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an `Input` inside the `Option`. What you can do is probably control the render using component state, controlled using the `Select`'s `onChange` event handler:

```
  state = {
    displayInput: false
  }

  handleChange(event, data) {
    this.setState({ displayInput: data.value === 'Other' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Relation :">
      {
        getFieldDecorator('Relation', {
          rules: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please provide relation!' },
            { max: 200, message: 'Note should be within a 200 characters' }
          ]
        })(
          <Select onChange={(event, data) => this.handleChange(event, data)}>
            <Option value="Father">Father</Option>
            <Option value="Mother">Mother</Option>
            <Option value="Husband">Husband</Option>
            <Option value="Other">Other</Option>
          </Select>
         )
       }
       {
         this.state.displayInput && (
           <Input placeholder="Other" type="text"/>
         )
       }
      </FormItem>
    );
  }
```

Comment: it should still be relevant, I have updated mine based on your question too

Comment: sir not working .when i select  the 'other'  then nothing happen

Comment: Probably `this.state.displayInput` is not `true`. I'm not sure what is the data coming through, can you check it with `handleChange(event, data) {
   console.log('data', data);
    this.setState({ displayInput: data === 'Other' });
  }` and let me know what is the data?

Comment: sir if i select Father then data is props: {…}

children: "Father"
value: "Father "

Comment: sir and if i select the Other then data is - props: {…}
​​
children: "Other"
​​
value: "Other"

Comment: I see, then you have to access into the props by `data.value`, I have updated the answer

Comment: sir when i select the other option not come input text .this mean i am unable to type anything

Comment: ah. it was because it was not bind together. I have update the answer

Comment: you may use arrow binding `() => this.handleChange()` or set it up in the constructor `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state  = { displayInput: false } ;
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }`

Comment: sir i gave
          <Select onChange={(event, data) => this.handleChange(event, data)}>  but not change  the  text field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174769/discussion-between-jee-mok-and-gnanaseelan).